# Negation of Content 0

Tags: logic, manifolds

I would like to know how to negate the definition of the following (Spivak, Calculus on Manifolds):

> A subset A of $R^n$ has (n-dimensional) content 0 if for every
>   $\epsilon >0$ there is a finite cover {$U_1 ,..., U_n $} of A by
>   closed rectangles such that  $$\sum_{i=1} ^n v(U_i) < \epsilon.$$

A small breakdown of these compound negations would also be helpful!
Thanks !

Comment: "For some (particular) $\epsilon$ there is no such cover - so for every finite cover the sum exceeds $\epsilon$".

Answer (score 2):

To negate a sentence with quantifiers, you just need to flip the type of each one - "for every" becomes "there exists", and "there exists" becomes "for every". Doing this one step at a time:

> A subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ *does not* have $n$-dimensional content $0$ if *it is not the case that* for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a finite cover $\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}$ of $A$ by closed rectangles so that $\sum_{i = 1}^nv(U_i) < \epsilon$.

is equivalent to

> A subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ *does not* have $n$-dimensional content $0$ if there is an $\epsilon > 0$ so that *it is not the case that* there is a finite cover $\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}$ of $A$ by closed rectangles with $\sum_{i = 1}^nv(U_i) < \epsilon$.

is equivalent to

> A subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ *does not* have $n$-dimensional content $0$ if there is an $\epsilon > 0$ so that for every finite cover $\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}$ of $A$ by closed rectangles *it is not the case that* $\sum_{i = 1}^nv(U_i) < \epsilon$.

is equivalent to

> A subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ *does not* have $n$-dimensional content $0$ if there is an $\epsilon > 0$ so that for every finite cover $\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}$ of $A$ by closed rectangles, $\sum_{i = 1}^nv(U_i) \geq \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

The negation is that for some $\varepsilon,$ there is no such cover.  That means that there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that for any finite cover by closed rectangles we have $$\sum_{i=1} ^n v(U_i) \ge \varepsilon.$$

Another way of looking at it is that the infimum of $\sum_{i=1} ^n v(U_i)$ over all such covers is positive.